# jquery resize window and mobile detect

Tags: jquery, mobile, resize

How to use mobile detect and window resize at the same time ? 
For example I have this bit of code

```
if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) || $(window).width() < 480 ){
    //do this
    }else{
    //do something else
}
```

and I want to write something similar to the above but check if the browser is mobile or if window is resized plus window width is less than 480 pixel. e.g. to combine the below code with the above code.

```
 $(window).resize(function() {
      if ($(window).width() < 480) {
         }else{}
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly you should be able to simply do this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) || $(window).width() < 480 ){
    //do this
    }else{
    //do something else
    }
}
```

Or, you could store the user agent in a variable before dom initialization:

```
var isMobile = /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(window).resize(function() {
         if ($(window).width() < 480 || isMobile) {
         // handle less than 480
         }else{
         //handle else
         }
     });
});
```

Comment: but would mobile detect work if it's inside the resize function? because mobile detect doesn't require window to resize.

Comment: Yes, it would still work because navigator is a globally available variable. Either option should do what you are looking for.