# Media query issue with react and styled-components while trying to use inline

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

So I have a screen that will change according to some media queries, this screen is made up of generic styled components and when I need a particular feature I include it inline with the component on the screen, some of this properties being positioning and or height/width.

After desigining for a desktop screen I am trying to implement a mobile screen.
Ill show some code

```
type Props = {
  setDisplayScreen: Function,
};

const SignIn = ({ setDisplayScreen }: Props) => (
  <ScreenDiv>
    <ImageContainer>
      <ImageDiv bg={sideimage} src={sideimage} alt="logo" />
    </ImageContainer>
    <FormDiv>
      <Input style={{ marginTop: 44 }} placeholder="Username" />
      <Input style={{ marginTop: 44 }} placeholder="Password" />
      <PinkButton style={{ marginTop: 45, width: 82, cursor: 'pointer' }}>
        Sign in
      </PinkButton>
      <NunitoItalic18 style={{ marginTop: 60 }}>
        Forgot username or password
      </NunitoItalic18>
      <Nunito20
        style={{ marginTop: 45.8, cursor: 'pointer' }}
        onClick={() => setDisplayScreen('SignUpOptions')}
      >
        Don’t have an account? Sign up
      </Nunito20>
    </FormDiv>
  </ScreenDiv>
);

export default SignIn;
```

My specific question is how can I change the url of the image in  according to screen size along with margin spaces according to the screen size?

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding an on resize event listener that changes a variable which you then use in your component

```
if (browserScreenSize === mobile) {
   //set margin and image for mobile
} else {
  //set margin and image for desktop
}
```

in your components you then specify the variable name instead of the value

Comment: I didnt really understand how to go about that

Comment: 1. Add an event listener to check whether you are on mobile or on desktop
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425688/jquery-resize-window-and-mobile-detect

2. Set a variable that you will edit on resize
let backgroundimg;
if (mobile) {
backgroundimg = 'url here'
}else {
backgroundimg = 'url here'
}

3. In your component use the variable instead of the url 
<img src={backgroundimg}>